# Jquery .html() not working with localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I first store html code locally using this script:

```
queuehistory = $("#queue").html();
localStorage.setItem("queuehistory", queuehistory);
```

When the page loads, I run a script that detects if the localstorage item has been set:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("queuehistory"))
{
  $("#queue").html(localStorage.getItem("queuehistory"));
}
```

Although localstorage has been set and does exist, for some reason the html code is not being loaded into $("#queue").

For testing purposes, I ran this bit of code:

```
 if (localStorage.getItem("queuehistory"))
 {
  alert(localStorage.getItem("queuehistory"));  
  $("#queue").html(localStorage.getItem("queuehistory"));
 }
```

localStorage.getItem is definitely not empty, so I have no idea why this bit of code does not seem to be working.  The storage itself works, but loading my locally stored html code into a div does not seem to work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is returned by `alert(localStorage.getItem("queuehistory")); ` and whether it is running on dom ready

Comment: The problem has been solved.  I am replacing the link to the test page that I have provided for privacy reasons.  Thanks!

Comment: alert(localStorage.getItem("queuehistory")); returns whatever is currently in the queue div.  It changes depending on what is in your queue.  It might simplify things if you take a look at the url to the test page that I provided.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place your code in side dom ready callback

```
$(function(){
    if (localStorage.getItem("queuehistory")){
        alert(localStorage.getItem("queuehistory"));
        $("#queue").html(localStorage.getItem("queuehistory"));
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  This solved my problem.  I can't believe that I missed this.

Answer (score 1):

localStorage only stores strings, you can't store a a Dom element.  (it might work with some browsers, but it's not in the specification, so don't use it in that way)

Comment: `typeof $("#some-element").html(); // 'string'`